# iPhone StoreKit: in App Purchase: Invalid Product id

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I know this question has been asked before but I am still facing issues with the in app purchase. 
I have read the apple document, followed the checklist of http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

But I am still facing problem in making the in app purchase to work. 
I followed a video tutorial to create the StoreKit, my codes are fine. When I do NSLog for 
        NSLog(@"Invalid productRequest count %d", [response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]);
        The result: Invalid productRequest count 1
I have submitted the binary code and rejected it. I hope this is not an issue for the IAP to work. 
What I am doing different in order to make the in App Purchase to work.

Can someone kindly advice me if I am making a mistake or what should I do to ensure the iap to work.

Your response will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working on jailbroken device, I'd suggest you to restore factory version and try again. Somewhat jailbroken device has an issue to run testing in app purchase in sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The steps taken to make the in-app-Purchase to work:

1) Created unique App ID: com.yakimbi.inAppPurchase

2) Created Provisioning Profile, download and installed it.

3) Add the application to iTunes Connect App Store.

4) Upload the app binary file, and rejected it. The status is Developer Rejected.

5) The product is added in Manage You in App Purchase, ProductID is com.yakimbi.inAppPurchase.ProductTest1, created as non-consumable item.

6) Wrote the StoreKit code to request the Product.

7) Waited for more then 48hours once the product is added.

8) Created a Test User account.

9) Updated the code with supporting transaction.

10) Sign Out my account on the device.

11) Run the app on the device.

12) But I get inValidPurchaseIdentifier count 1.

13) Never got prompted for username and password.

What steps have I left out while creating this. I hope someone could guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to remove the app manually from the device.
- Sign out of your account on the device.
- Then reset the device and try again.

These worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted my Macbook, and it worked.